# Logs from alexa skill

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, alexa-skills-kit

I am new to developing alexa skills, and I wanted to do some logging to get information on what's going on.

I'm using Alexa Developers Console to create a simple Hello World skill, then I added a console.log(speakOutput); to the response.

I test the skill on the emulator and then head to the "Logs: Amazon CloudWatch" link. When I enter the cloudwatch, I get an error:
[image: Error on cloudwatch]

Also, if I try navigating by any of the menus I get permission errors. I know the only solution I found on the internet was to give execution permissions to the lambda function, but on the account I'm logged in when I click the link I don't have permissions to do that.

[image: User in cloudwatch]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can end up timing out of the developer console. Have you tried logging out of the developer.amazon.com console, then logging back in, opening your skill editor tab, and trying the Cloudwatch link again? You just may need some cookies refreshed.

Comment: Sorry for late response, I've been busy. Yes I tried that out, also, I tried in other computer and still the same.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? If you're syncing it with Google, it can share your state for some sites between computers. Make sure you log out of developer.amazon.com, log out of AWS, then just log back into developer.amazon.com. If you still can't access it, then you'll need to contact Alexa support because something is likely broken that you can't fix on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The user you're logged in as does not have access to CloudWatch logs.

You must grant this user permissions via IAM to read cloudwatch log streams.

There is a ready made policy named `CloudWatchLogsReadOnlyAccess` you can attached for this read only access.

Comment: I created an AWS account, but that user (VoiceHubSSORole/...) is not created. I think My acount is not the one used by Alexa Developer Console.

Comment: Did you create the Lambda code in the Alexa console?

Comment: yes, I did that folowing this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CzTKDu7Qgjs&feature=emb_rel_end

Comment: If OP followed the video, it's a hosted skill, which means they're coming in as an IAM user created for that skill. That user can't edit policies. Just bringing up the IAM console should give errors.